# HTML input form disable tags

Tags: php, html

I have an page where every one may post something, to an category. But the problem is that I know some of the people who are going to post something on mine website they will use html/javascript tags. I tried it by myself, when I submit something like a , text boxes even embed video's which I don't want. This will ruin my site. Does somebody know what to use for this? thank you

Comment: [htmlspecialchars()](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) to sanitize the input from HTML issues without losing the integrity of the information.

Comment: It should not matter, use prepared statements to enter things in the database and `htmlspecialchars` when you output to html.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`htmlspecialchars`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) will sanitize characters that have a special meaning in HTML (make sure that you *don't* turn off `double_encode`).

Comment: I'm very new to this, Maybe also a stupid question where do I need to put `htmlspecialchars`? my part of the code: http://pastebin.com/AHpVbJmL thank you very much

Comment: @Hadscape You need to use it everywhere you output user generated content. In your case: Around every variable inside your `echo` statements.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [strip_tags](https://www.php.net/strip_tags) method if you're worried about malicious scripts executing when you post back to the page.